# How to Perform a Card Burn Animation

Tags: swift, animation, core-animation, caemitterlayer

I want to perform a card burn animation like I have a card of Spade and I want it to view like burn animation like burning from the bottom of card to top of the card and disappear at same time where it is burn . I know that i can use `CAEmitterLayer` or Particle effect but I don't exactly know how can I use these. Can Anyone tell me how can I perform this?

```
let particleEffect = CAEmitterLayer()
let emitterCell = CAEmitterCell()
emitterCell.birthRate = 0.5
emitterCell.velocity = 10.0
emitterCell.lifetime = 100
```

Comment: You can refer this link: https://github.com/lexrus/LTMorphingLabel/blob/master/LTMorphingLabel/LTMorphingLabel%2BBurn.swift. The library is doing a similar thing with UILabel. Basically, It is about masking image.

Comment: But this thing i have to perform on imageView ?

Comment: Yea there's basically two parts to your answer - masking/hiding the "burned up" portion of the card, and adding the particles. On that emitter you also need to set the size etc if you want it to look like the bottom edge is burning.